# Loop won't stop, leads to overflow

Tags: excel, vba, loops, overflow

I am new to VBA, this seems simple, but when I run the code it continues to create random numbers until it finally gives me an overflow message. I can tell it can read the total, but I don't know why it won't stop.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim total As Integer
i = 1
total = Range("C1")

Do While total < 180
    Cells(i, 1).Value = Int((10 - 3 + 1) * Rnd + 3)
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're testing `total`, but you're incrementing `i`.  And I'm not at all certain that `total` updates automatically.  I think you have to get the range again inside the loop.

Comment: I am guessing your number gets larger than 32bits leading to an overflow. Try a long. **edit, total never increments!

Comment: So what is going to make total >= 180? Nothing, not even a change to C1

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Presumably the OP believes that Cells(i,1) is within the range "C1"  I don't think it is, but.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Aye Do While Range("C1") < 180 would have made some sense, unless total is a reference??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that C1 has some type of a sum or something that is growing while the VBA is populating numbers if that is the case then you just need to re-evaluate total at the end of each loop. This was working for me...

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim total As Integer
i = 1
total = Range("C1")

Do While total < 180
    Cells(i, 1).Value = Int((10 - 3 + 1) * Rnd + 3)
    i = i + 1
    Application.Calculate 'Only needed if manual calculation is on
    total = Range("C1")
Loop
```

Comment: Nice catch. It was a subtle issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using the wrong variable for your while loop.  Do you mean total < 180 or i < 180?